# How to store (and retrieve) a cookie array with Angular cookies

Tags: angularjs, cookies, setcookie

I'm trying to store my cookies with AngularJS as an array to keep the cookie file clean.

I'm using the following method:

```
$cookies.put('myCookieArray',{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'});
```

Now, when I try to retrieve it using:

```
getmycookiesback = $cookies.get('myCookieArray');
console.log(getmycookiesback.key1);
```

I get an `undefined` value.

but when I try to retrieve it using this:

```
console.log($rootScope.getmycookiesback);
```

It retrieves `[object Object]`.

What am I doing wrong? I want to get the value from *key1* and *key2*.

Comment: What if try getmycookiesback = $cookies.getObject('myCookieArray');?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$cookies.putObject('myCookieArray',{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'});` and `getmycookiesback = $cookies.getObject('myCookieArray');`

Comment: After testing on my app, this solution ultimately solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

try like that:

```
 DemoApp.controller('DemoController', function ($cookies, $scope, $log) {

            //$cookies.put('myCookieArray',{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'});
            $cookies['myCookieArray']= {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'};

            getmycookiesback = $cookies['myCookieArray'];
            $log.info(getmycookiesback.key1);  
        })
```

here the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/k9fltjGUbTbfbVlAmRcJ

I hope it helps